# How to add text to circle in force collapsible layout d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm working on force directed collapsible using this source https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288. It went well and i can adjust the circle size, gravity, etc but when i add text into the circle eventually the circle went static (can not be dragged) like in this image,
[static circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciy8q.gif)

This is my code to add text

```
node.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
  .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", click)
  .call(force.drag);
 
node.enter().append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

I already tried this code too but it didn't work.

```
var circle = node.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
  .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", click)
  .call(force.drag);
 
circle.append("text")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```